# Change EditText inputType programmatically without clearing values

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-8.1-oreo

I have a program I'm upgrading from Android 7.1.1 to now 8.1. Most things have gone incredibly smoothly, but I have hit a snag on one thing.

I have a postal code entry using an EditText. This entry begins initially with an InputType of ClassText and as the user enters their characters, I am swapping back and forth from ClassText to ClassNumber to get a resulting format such as: "M1N2J8"

On 7.1.1 this works, no problems. However, the behavior seems to have changed in 8.1. When I enter "M" and then "1", I have no problem, but after I have changed it back to ClassText to enter the "N" it wipes out the "1" and leaves me with "MN"

I would greatly appreciate any insights anyone may be able to offer on how I can get around this. Worst case scenario, I'll simply enable an alphanumeric keyboard and handle the restricting the characters myself, but my client greatly prefers to have the keyboards swap between text and number entry, so that's my goal right now.

Thanks!

```
if (txt.SelectionStart == 0 || txt.SelectionStart == 2 || txt.SelectionStart == 4)
            {
                txt.InputType = InputTypes.ClassText | InputTypes.TextFlagCapCharacters;
                txt.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new InputFilterLengthFilter(maxLength), new AlphaInputFilter() });
            }
            else if (txt.SelectionStart == 1 || txt.SelectionStart == 3 || txt.SelectionStart == 5)
            {
                txt.InputType = InputTypes.ClassNumber;
                txt.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new InputFilterLengthFilter(maxLength), new NumberInputFilter() });
            }
```

Comment: Your AlphaInputFilter and NumberInputfilter are causing the problem, can you show how are you implementing them??

Comment: Changing the InputType plus the LengthFilter should be enough, at the end your desired value is alphanumeric, It won't fit on any of your InputFilters

Comment: Oh jeez, you're right. How stupid of me.... Okay, I'll remove the Alpha and Numeric filters and just replace them with my own character handling. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the second InputFilter, Your final output is alphanumeric and won't fit on any of them

```
if (txt.SelectionStart == 0 || txt.SelectionStart == 2 || txt.SelectionStart == 4)
{
    txt.InputType = InputTypes.ClassText | InputTypes.TextFlagCapCharacters;
    txt.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new InputFilterLengthFilter(maxLength) });
}
else if (txt.SelectionStart == 1 || txt.SelectionStart == 3 || txt.SelectionStart == 5)
{
    txt.InputType = InputTypes.ClassNumber;
    txt.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new InputFilterLengthFilter(maxLength) });
}
```

Comment: It is still odd however that my original code worked perfectly on 7.1.1. And also that here on 8.1 now the AlphaInputFilter seems to be the only one that's problematic, meaning of course, that when I enabled the NumberInputFilter it did not similarly wipe out my Alpha characters.

Comment: Is keepOriginal = false on any of the InputFilters?

Comment: Probably both have the same issue, but you never get there since the first filter changes the SelectionStart value

Comment: Aha, yeah. It comes down to what characters are allowed. I'm showing a Numeric entry keyboard but checking IsDigit on the Numeric one, not just for numbers, so only the Alpha one ever becomes KeepOriginal = false. Thanks again :)